What's the phrasal verb "take up" mean in "...a shot that interrupts the main action of a film or television program to take up a related subject"
This is a definition for the headword "cutaway" from the Merriam-Webster dictionary:
: a shot that interrupts the main action of a film or television program to take up a related subject or to depict action supposed to be going on at the same time as the main action
What's "take up" mean here?

To adopt or begin something new.

I'll be taking up a position as head of IT at an insurance company.
We're taking up a new research methodology that should improve the reliability of our results. (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2024)

To resume or start something again after an interruption or hiatus. A noun or pronoun can be used between "take" and "up."

And with that, we're out of time. Let's take this discussion up on Monday, shall we?
After I came back from London, we took things up again as if I had never left. (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2024)

[for someone or a group] to deliberate something.

When will the board of directors take this up? Let's take up that matter now. (McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms).


To adopt or begin [to discuss] something new.


Definitions 1 and 2 are pretty much the same; the distinction lies entirely in whether the thing being taken up is new or not.  I don't see the point in listing them separately.  I'd just define it as "start or turn one's attention to" and note that it may be, but needn't be, the first time one has started or turned one's attention to that thing.

Well, it should be pretty easy to see that 3 isn't relevant. The camera doesn't "deliberate," i.e. "discuss."
It ought to be easy to see how either 1 or 2 could both be relevant, though. The only difference is that one is "starting something new" and the other is "starting something again after a break." Film editing does both. You might "cut away" from one plot thread to a secondary one for the first time, or you might cut back to the main thread and then back to the "cutaway" for not-the-first-time.

to take up a subject in any media, text or conversation means:
to address the subject.
Often used in meetings: We will now take up the issue of [x].
It is not related to how a subject is dealt with, just that it is dealt with.
From the OP:
a shot that interrupts the main action of a film or television program to take up a related subject=
From Me:
a shot that interrupts the main action of a film or television program to deal with a related subject

Sometimes in films there can be several scenes happening at the same time, or there are flashbacks that can provide vital information to the plot.
A cutaway is an edit that allows filmgoers (or the person watching it at home) to show a different subject or view what is happening to a different character. It's like being at two or more places at the same time, so take up, in this instance, means being informed about the story, you take up from where it was left.
